# Compare byte values?

Tags: java, comparison, byte

I'm curious to know why, when I compare a `byte` array with a value...

```
boolean match = ((data[0] & 0xFF) == 0xFE);
```

...returns `true`, while...

```
boolean match = (data[0] == 0xFE);
```

...does not? `data` is a `byte` array with

```
data[0] = (byte) 0xFE;
```

Comment: Are you getting any compiler warnings? I think those might be integer literals (and then the comparison might be done as int, with your negative number in the array and the positive integer literal).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
boolean match = ((data[0] & 0xFF) == 0xFE);
```

compares integers as 0xFF is an integer, this expression **will scale up your byte** `data[0]` to an  int and compare what's inside the parenthesis to a second int `0xFE(254)`. As you say `data[0]` is `(byte)0xFE`, it will first be scaled to the integer `0xFE` and compared to the integer `0xFE`, so this works.

```
boolean match = (data[0] == 0xFE);
```

compares a byte to the int `0xFE` : `254`

```
data[0] = (byte) 0xFE;
```

is a byte (so it's [signed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) and its value is `-2`.

`-2` is not equal to `254`, so that's why you must compare data[0] as a byte or as scale it up to an integer before comparing it the integer `0xFE`.

A simpler comparison could be

```
boolean match = (data[0] == (byte)0xFE);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it has to do with promoting 0xFF to an int with sign extension. In the first expression, 0xFE is also promoted to an int and therefore the result of `data[0] & 0xFF` is also an int and an int comparison is done.

But in the second code sample, there is no operation being done and so there is no promotion to int. That is to say, that data[0] does not get promoted to int but 0xFE is an int.