# Compare a byte and hexadecimal

Tags: java, hex, byte

I have a byte array which I need to traverse and based on the byte value do something. Below is my code for this.

```
    for (byte b:byteArray)
    {

        if(b>=(byte)0x00 && b<=(byte)0x1F)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if(b>=(byte)0x20 && b <=(byte)0xFE)
        {   
             //do something
        }
        else if(b ==(byte)0xFF)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

My problem the byte comparison is not happening as per my expectation.

Assume the values in my byte array is `{31, -117, 8, 0 , -1}`, the code I have is not able to detect all negative byte values in their respective range. For ex. -117 should be between `0x20` and `0xFE` , but it is not going to any of the range.

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392351/compare-byte-values#13392474) to compare bytes. I cannot figure out what is wrong in the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `(byte)0xFE` is actually `-2`

Comment: Byte are signed in Java. `b <=(byte)0xFE` is therefore only true of two values: 0xfe and 0xff.

Comment: @EJP How should I change my logic to cover all possible bytes in the following two range: `0x00-0x1f` and `0x20-0xFE`. Sorry if the question is very basic but I have not been able to figure out.

Comment: @Fildor, It doesn't go in any of the condition.

Comment: EJP's comment nails it. Relational operators don't work as you expect. Try comparing Integers instead of bytes. Because you expect values from 0-255 whereas the operators work on -128 to 127 ... The answer you linked only fixes comparing distinct values, no relations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your relations only make sense on unsigned bytes - which do not exist in Java.

Try this:

```
for (byte b:byteArray)
{
    int ib = b & 0xFF;         // This scales up to integer so you have values 0-255
    if(ib >=0x00 && ib<=0x1F)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if(ib>=0x20 && ib <=0xFE)
    {   
         //do something
    }
    else if(ib == 0xFF)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        // log a bug! This should never happen!
    }
}
```

In your solution -117 is 0x8B , which is in fact less than 0x20 (Dec 32), so it does not meet the 2nd path criteria `b >= 0x20`. In fact this creates unreachable code because **no** value is > 32 **and** <= -2.

Answer (score 3):

Bytes in Java are signed by default. A workaround to have unsigned bytes is something similar to having : `int num = (int) bite & 0xFF`

How it works, Let's suppose `byte b = -128`;, this is represented as `1000 0000`

`int num = (int)b;` num is now -128 and binary representation is like this:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
```

Lets compare `num & 0xFF` in binary?

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
&
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

The result is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000`, which is 128, meaning your signed value is converted to unsigned value.