# Java primitve conversion in switch and method calls

Tags: java

I am reading rules of conversion for primitives and their wrapper classes and I feel that there is different behavior and rules for conversion in different context. I have two cases/context to present.

case 1: switch statements

```
Integer x = 10;
final byte a = 3;       
System.out.println(x == a); // work fine
switch (x) {
case a: // Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to Integer
    System.out.println("It’s OK.");
}
```

Look at this when comparing byte and Integer it work fine but in switch it give error. Why?

case 2: method calls
I read that java convert to next big type if no exact type match during method call. For example

```
public static void one(int i, long n){System.out.println("first");}
public static void one(double i, int n){System.out.println("three");}

// call
one(13, 12); // The method one(int, long) is ambiguous for the type Method
```

It should call the first method according to rule because long is bigger next to int. So what are the rules in these two cases?

Comment: Your two examples are quite different. One involves auto-unboxing *and* a narrowing primitive conversion. The other involves `int` and `double` and method selection. It's not clear how they're meant to relate to one another, as they involve different things (comparison vs. method selection) and different issues (boxing and conversion within related types vs. between disparate types).

Comment: For one thing, if `x` is null, you'll get a `NullPointerException` anyway; so change it to `switch (x.intValue())`.

Comment: A similar question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392351/compare-byte-values though scalling is not quite the correct term

Comment: Your `System.out.println(x == a); // work fine` does not work fine at all. It is essentially `Integer.valueOf(10).equals(Byte.valueOf(3))`which is obviously would return `false` as the types are different...

Comment: work fine mean compile successfully

Comment: @AndyTurner if `x` is null, `x.intValue()` will also throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto It is not the same as `Integer.valueOf(10).equals(Byte.valueOf(3))`. `a` is a primitive, which will cause `Integer x` to be auto-unboxed and both will be compared as primitive integers, not as objects.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak indeed it will - my point was *not* to get rid of the NPE, but to get rid of the confusing boxing of the case values, which is just complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: With operators, byte,char and short is automatically converted to int so `System.out.println(x == a);` is ok. Bu for switch the rule is not valid.
Case 2: Java does not know if `12` is long or int because you can write a long like `12` and `12L`.  So changing to `12L` clears the ambiguousness